# How to insert file content into another file?

Tags: linux, alpine-linux

**confi.ini** (BEFORE)

```
[DEFAULT]
## Default settings ######################
debug = false

[app:main]
abc=def
ghfi=kftest

## General settings ######################
use=hello
test1.test2=test3

[logger]
level=INFO
handlers=console
```

**extra_conf.ini**

```
security.host=localhost
security.username=test
security.password=test12345
```

Can I know how do I use command to insert the extra_conf.ini file content into the confi.ini, under the [app.main]? I googled and found sed command, but I can't seem to do it as per the expected_confi.ini file, can someone please assist?

**expected_confi.ini** (AFTER changed)

```
[DEFAULT]
## Default settings ######################
debug = false

[app:main]
security.host=localhost
security.username=test
security.password=test12345
abc=def
ghfi=kftest

## General settings ######################
use=hello
test1.test2=test3

[logger]
level=INFO
handlers=console
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `sed` to print just part of a file.

It's import to understand `sed` process one line at a time, printing the result. The basic usage is to match a string and execute a command.

So you can get your desired file by:

1. Print lines from **confi.ini**, up to `[app:main]`:

   `sed "/\[app:main\]/q" confi.ini`, where the `q` command quits sed, so we're printing everything until finding `[app:main]`.
2. Print all lines from **extra_conf.ini**:

   `cat extra_conf.ini`
3. Print lines from **confi.ini**, except the ones from the start to `[app:main]`:

   `sed "1,/\[app:main\]/d" confi.ini`, where the `d` command deletes lines 1 to the line with `[app:main]`.

Redirecting to **new_conf.ini** and putting it all together in a single-line command.

```
sed "/\[app:main\]/q" confi.ini > new_conf.ini; cat extra_conf.ini >> new_conf.ini; sed "1,/\[app:main\]/d" confi.ini >> new_conf.ini
```

Be sure that `extra_conf.ini` has no line break at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to do this with sed is:

```
sed -e '/^\[app:main\]$/rextra_conf.ini' confi.ini > expected_confi.ini
```

The pattern `^\[app:main\]$` matches the header of the section, and the `r` command reads the named file into the input stream.  The command looks a little weird here, and the string `rextra_conf.ini` is the command `r` followed by the name of the file to be read into the stream.

Comment: thank you for the detailed. May I check with you, whether is it possible to put into the confi.ini instead of expected_conf.ini?

Comment: Some versions of `sed` have a `-i` flag that will do the overwrite for you.  Or you can write a wrapper that does it.  Or you can do `sed ... > tmp && mv tmp confi.ini`